# List of Custom post type categories and their posts

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, posts

I have been searching all over for this and none of the code here seems to work for me. I have a custom post type called Products and within each one of them they have specific child categories.

For example within Products is:

- Hi Fi Compoments
  -- Amplifiers
- Home Theater
  -- AV Recievers 
  -- Stereo Recievers
  -- Systems
- Portable audio
  -- DIgital audio players

What I would like to do is call the first subcategory as well as the next level with a list of that levels posts. So for example

Home Theater
- AVRecievers
-- list of AV Receiver Posts
- Stereo Systems
-- List of Stereo Systems Posts
- Systems
-- List of Systems Posts

I have run up against two problems with the code I have found:
1. For whatever reason when I define a custom post type of Products it pulls every category within the wordpress database.

Or

2. When it does pull in just the specific Products categories, they are all out of order and not in any parent structure anymore.

I have the post type and its registered and working properly elsewhere. I have included the post type reg, from the functions.php as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
register_post_type( 'Products',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies'=> array('category'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
        )
    );
}
```

Heres an example of code I tried from here that displays the sub categories but there is no parent child relationship and its pulling categories like NEWS which is not in Products, nor are there posts.

```
 <?php
       $args = array(
       'type'                     => 'products',
       'child_of'                 => 0,
       'parent'                   => '',
       'orderby'                  => 'name',
       'order'                    => 'ASC',
       'hide_empty'               => 1,
       'hierarchical'             => 1,
       'pad_counts'               => false );
       $categories = get_categories($args);
       echo '<ul>';

       foreach ($categories as $category) {
         $url = get_term_link($category);?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
         <?php
       }
       echo '</ul>';
   ?>
```

Comment: the category is a default WP taxonomy registered for default post type if you are using custom post type have you tried register custom taxonomy to avoid any situations like this?

Comment: the Post type is already registered within functions.php. With the categories the user is allowed to add new ones within the post type, so not sure if you mean to register each cat (term). I wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: you see when you have a custom post type like "product" what you need to do is add a custom taxonomy "product_cat" but you simply assigned default WordPress taxonomy to your custom post type. As a result, you have mixed data like news and products on your website.

Comment: I've tried that, and if i remove the category, the backend loses the ability to add and display categories within the Post type. Is there something.

\\\Ive replaced:  'taxonomies'=> array('category'),

with:
 \\\taxonomies'=> array('product_cat),

And now can not add categories.

Comment: Have you properly registered "product_cat" taxonomy and assigned it to "product" post type? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: register_post_type( 'Products',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
   'taxonomies'=> array('product_ca'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
        )
    );
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192929/discussion-between-artem-and-jamie).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `get_terms()`. This allows you to configure which taxonomy you want to retrieve terms for.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy' => 'Products',
  'hide_empty' => true,
) );
```

The returned Term objects will include parent term info and give you the ID's and slugs needed to query for posts that are in each term.

Full resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: That wasn't acutally it @Artem helped me out a ton. I needed to register the custom taxonomy that the categories were specific to the post type. Previously I was mixing up using custom post type and regular categories. His help has led me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  register_post_type( 'Products',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),

            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );


function my_taxonomies_product() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Product Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Product Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' ),

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'products', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
```

Thats what helped me once I actually defined the custom taxonomy as cats I can now distinguish between the two types of posts.